# Loop head inside try-block in python

Tags: python, for-loop, try-catch, iterable

I define an iterable like this:

```
class MyClass:
    
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        
    def __iter__(self):       
        for item in self.arg:
            yield item
```

Unfortunately `arg` might be `None`. I wonder how to catch this in style. I can do:

```
def __iter__(self):
    if self.arg is None:
        return
    for item in self.arg:
        yield item
```

But this does not comply with python's EAFP style. Maybe this way:

```
def __iter__(self):
    try:
        for item in self.arg:
            yield item
    except TypeError:
        return
```

But this seems dangerous to me. Actually, my loop is much more involved and I do not want any other TypeErrors to pass unnoticed. Can I restrict the try-block to the head of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you consider `arg` being `None` to be an error.

If it's a supported value that just means there's nothing to work on then checking for it and returning, as per your first solution, makes the most sense.

If it should never be `None` and someone passing that in is an error then just let the exception happen. Or, my personal choice, check it and throw an exception in `__init__` to say the caller passed an invalid argument. Exceptions happening earlier (at the time the invalid thing happened) feels better than them happening later once a bunch of other things are going on and it's harder to figure out.